# Uncaught Error: Ziggy error: route 'batch.run' is not in the route list

Tags: laravel-8, inertiajs

I have setup a Laravel8 blog demo application to learn the ins/outs of Laravel8. However, after creating a new controller (copy of PostsController called BatchesController), adding the resource to the web.php, only the default routes work such as edit/create/destroy. I tried adding a new route, only to get the following error: "Uncaught Error: Ziggy error: route 'batch.run' is not in the route list".

batch.run is my new route and it pretty much is a copy of the "destroy" route that is already setup for deleting the posts. I do not understand what I am doing wrong when I am simply using something that is a near copy of the default routes. Where do these routes get "added" when using the cover-all "resource" in web.php. Shouldn't it just run any method in the controller based on the name of the route?

Here is my web.php:

```
    Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('showLoginForm')->middleware('guest');
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegisterForm'])->name('showRegisterForm')->middleware('guest');

Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('login');
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register');

Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

Route::resource('post', PostsController::class);
Route::resource('batch', BatchesController::class);
Route::resource('token', TokensController::class);
Route::resource('home', HomeController::class);

Route::redirect('/', 'home');
```

Here is my controller method:

```
    public function run(Request $request, $id) {
    Batch::find($id)->run();
    $request->session()->flash('success', 'Batch run successfully!');
    return redirect()->route('batch.running');
}
```

Here is my .vue file (minus the template):

```html
<script>
import AppHeader from "../../Partials/AppHeader";
import ErrorsAndMessages from "../../Partials/ErrorsAndMessages";
import {usePage} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import {Inertia} from "@inertiajs/inertia";
import {computed, inject} from "vue";

export default {
    name: "Batches",
    components: {
        ErrorsAndMessages,
        AppHeader
    },
    props: {
        errors: Object
    },
    setup() {
        const route = inject('$route');

        const deleteBatch = (id) => {
            if (!confirm('Are you sure want to delete #' + id + '?')) return;
            Inertia.delete(route('batch.destroy', {id}));
        }

        const runBatch = (id) => {
            if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to run #' + id + '?')) return;
            Inertia.post(route('batch.run', {id}));
        }

        const batches = computed(() => usePage().props.value.batches);

        const numberLinks = batches.value.links.filter((v, i) => i > 0 && i < batches.value.links.length - 1);

        return {
            batches,
            deleteBatch,
            runBatch,
            numberLinks
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .action-btn {
        margin-left: 12px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .article {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: You need to define the route manually. `Route::resource()` only generates routes for the usual CRUD operations. It does not make routes for any extra endpoints you put in the controller.

Comment: Apparently I cannot even post an answer now because someone's feelings got hurt by me asking for an explanation of my answers being deleted.............

So, since I cannot answer this question............

As @BrianOrtiz pointed out in response to my post, you have to manually define the additional routes. I'd like to know why the canned routes work fine without definitions, but that is a solution for another day I guess.

So, again, add a route in your web.php or wherever you are defining the routes for your app. The simple Route::resource will not cover these additional routes.

Comment: `resource()` is meant as a shortcut for making a RESTful API

Answer (score 3):

Try to give name to the route.

```
Route::get('gifts/list','GiftsController@list')->name("gifts.list");
```

and call the route using the route function

```
 let listUrl = route("gifts.list");
```

The above solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This instruction:

```
Route::resource('batch', BatchesController::class);
```

Does not create a route named "batch.run" automatically.  Only creates these: [batch.index, batch.create, batch.store, batch.edit, batch.update and batch.destruct or batch.delete].

If you want to use "batch.run" you need to create it manually like:

```
Route::post('batchRun', [BatchesController::class, 'run'])->name('batch.run');
```